# Sorting data from table field octobercms

Tags: sorting, octobercms

I want to show data in order of column where the num are given in octobercms,

default.htm

```
{% set post = __SELF__.post %}

<div class="content">{{ post.content_html|raw }}</div>

{% if post.featured_images.count %}
    <div class="featured-images text-center">
        {% for image in post.featured_images %}
            <p>
                <img
                    data-src="{{ image.filename }}"
                    src="{{ image.path }}"
                    alt="{{ image.description }}"
                    style="max-width: 100%" />
            </p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}

<p class="info">
    Posted
    {% if post.categories.count %} in
        {% for category in post.categories %}
            <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.name }}</a>{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    on {{ post.published_at|date('M d, Y') }}
</p>
<p class="info">

    {% for blocks in post.blocks %}  // here the output of this loop must show in order which are given in column in same table which is relation_sort_order
    <b> {{ blocks.title}}</b>

    {{ blocks.content_html|raw }}

    {% endfor %}
</p>
```

how i can show the blocks in number in relation_sort_order field

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `post` variable is a custom Model object, and `blocks` is a relation on that object, the best way to do what you are asking to is to update the relationship definition in the model class that defines your `post` object.

You didn't include the code for that, but it probably looks something like this:

```
public $hasMany = [
    'blocks' => 'Acme\Blog\Models\Block'
]
```

You can update that to include a sort order by default, see this [section of the OctoberCMS documentation](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/relations#detailed-relationships)

But in short, you would change the above to this:

```
public $hasMany = [
    'blocks' => [
        'Acme\Blog\Models\Block', 
        'order' => 'relation_sort_order asc'
    ]
];
```

Then anytime in you accessed the `blocks` relationship from your `Post` class, it would automatically sort it in that order.